# Should I use a rails integer id for an imported public data table that uses fixed length strings for id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv, database-design

I need to use a public government data table, imported via csv as a table in my rails application (using postgresql). The table in question uses a fixed length 12 digit numeric string (often with at least one leading zero) as its primary key. I feel as if I have three choices here:

1. Add a rails-generated integer primary key upon import
2. Ask rails to interpret the string as an integer and use that as my primary key.
3. Force rails to use a string as the primary key (and then, subsequently as the foreign key in other associated tables as well)

I'm worried about doing choice 1 because I will likely need to re-import this government data wholesale at least yearly as it gets updated in order to keep my database current. It seems like it would be really complicated to ensure that the rails primary keys stay with the correct record after a re-import if records have been added and deleted

Choice 2 seems like the way to go, (it would solve the re-import problem) but I'm not clear how to go about it. Is it as simple as telling rails to import that column as an integer?

Choice 3 seems doable, but in posts I've read elsewhere, it's not a very "railsy" way to go about it.

I'd welcome any advice or out and out solutions on this.

**Update**

I ended up using choice 1, and it was the right choice. That's becauseI am new to rails, and had thought I'd be doing some direct, bulk import (on the back end, directly into Postgresql) would leave me with the problem I described above. However, I looked through Railscast 369 which explains how to build csv import capabilities into your application as an end-user function. It's remarkably easy and that's what I did. As a result of doing things this way, the application does a row-by-row import, and can thus have the appropriate checks built in at that level.

Comment: Look into writing a foreign data wrapper. Then create a materialized view that pulls it in full, so as to manipulate local data without any network overhead. And then refresh it every so often.

Comment: The important things:
- Use an integer as the primary key so you can make fast queries to your table.
- Have a way to determine the primary key out of an incoming register. You could either turn that string you talk about or another field as long as it's unique.

Comment: Denis: looked into this. It's almost certainly beyond my still-meager capabilities at this point. Someday... Louis Ortega Araneda & mu is too short: as per my update, this is the solution I went with. Thanks to all for your help!